# Windows 2008 R2 Installation Blue Screen - PXE Installation on ESXI

Tags: windows-server-2008, vmware-esxi, pxe-boot

So the story begins with the PXE automated installation on dedicated servers and virtual servers.

I am trying to boot operating systems using PXE (using ipxe scripts) and perform automated installations on them. Linux operating systems are being installed without any issues. I also have no issues with installing Windows Server 2008/2012 directly on physical servers.

However I wanted to do it on virtual machines (I am using VMware ESXi 5.x on my end). After everything is loaded (like `bootmgr.exe`, `bcd`, `boot.sdi`, `wgl4_boot.ttf`, `boot.wim`) and the server boots, I get a blue screen:

[image: Blue Screen]

Does anyone have any idea why I am getting this and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, after searching around and asking some friends they suggested me to make sure my VPS has only one vCPU assigned to it ( which was not the case, I had 4vCPU on that VPS ). I reduced the vcpu and booted it again, and now it is working.

Now I have to find some fixes for this esxi bug.